# User does not have permission to access this object even User is logged

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I am logged in with the Firebase, and trying to access the images with these rules, I have seen other question related to this. but non of those are logged in and faced same problem.

```
rules_version = '2';
 service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
}
}
}
```

> but I face this error:
> 2023-04-27 13:43:32.740 8930-9032/com.studyo.studyo E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
> User does not have permission to access this object.
> Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403

However, if I change the rules for everyone, then i don't see that error.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
 match /b/{bucket}/o {
 match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write;
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Security rules don't do anything on their own yet, but only become active once you execute code against them. Please edit your code to include the [minimal code with which any of us can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). --- Also: neither of the rules you share require the user to be logged in, so it seems that their sign-in state should not be relevant here.